# Low level code for a shell in C that needs to be able to change directories using getcwd(), getenv(), and chdir()

Tags: arrays, c, shell, pointers

I am working on a project where I need to create a shell that is able to switch between directories and continuously output the current directory, exactly how it normally is in Linux.

Here is the code I have thus far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buf[BUFFERSIZE];
    int n;
    printf("1730sh:~$ \n");
    while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0)
    {
        buf[n] = 0;
        buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
        int i = 0;
        char* array[10];
        char* token1 = strtok(buf, " ");
        char* newarray[10];
        int exitIndicator = 0;
        char* directOut;
        char* directory;

        while ((token1 != NULL))
        {
            array[i++] = token1;
            token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }//while

        array[i] = NULL;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (!strcmp(array[j], "cd"))
            {
                directory = array[j+1];
                int change = chdir(directory);
                exitIndicator = 1;
            }
        }
        printf("1730sh:~%s$ \n", directory);
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is after changing directories from the beginning, if I enter another command and run it, it goes back to its home directory.

Ps: in the full code, cat file1.txt works as it should, so just assume that it works and outputs what it should.

```
./main
1730sh:~$ 
cd Ghioalda-Edward-p3
1730sh:~Ghioalda-Edward-p3$ 
cat file1.txt
1730sh:~$
```

Comment: why does your code also match xxcd or 123cd?

Comment: @stark could you elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: what is your j loop for?

Comment: @stark whatever the user inputs get broken down and entered into an array. The for loop checks each item in the array and sees if it is a certain value, in this case, "cd"

Comment: So it will match if user types "foo baz cd" and try to chdir to nonexistent 4th element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the command is *not* `cd` then you have these two lines:

```
char* directory;
printf("1730sh:~%s$ \n", directory);
```

You're printing using the ***uninitialized*** pointer `directory`, a pointer whose value (where it's pointing) is *indeterminate*, and that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

As a simple solution I recommend you create another variable, an array, to hold the current directory. Define that variable *outside* the main reading loop, and copy into that when you change directory.

So something like

```
char current_directory[256] = "";  // Initialize to the empty string

printf("1730sh:~$ \n");
while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0)
{
    // ...

    if (!strcmp(array[j], "cd"))
    {
        strcpy(current_directory, array[j+1]);
        int change = chdir(current_directory);
    }

    // ...

    printf("1730sh:~%s$ \n", current_directory);
}
```